# How to serialize ID command and parameter list described in rfc2971 IMAP ID extension

Tags: imap, rfc

Example:

```
C: a023 ID ("name" "sodr" "version" "19.34" "vendor" "Pink Floyd Music Limited")
S: * ID NIL
S: a023 OK ID completed
```

When I send the command and parameters via socket to server, how to serialize such things: ("name" "sodr" "version" "19.34" "vendor" "Pink Floyd Music Limited")?

Comment: It's just pairs of quoted strings, between parentheses, exactly as you see in the example.

Comment: @Max Thank you, This one is accepted. Not able to upvote your help now, I really want to downvote Stack Exchange App

Comment: I will change to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just pairs of quoted strings between parentheses, exactly as shown in the example.